# Excel VBA Report, Selecting Cells by a criteria

Tags: ms-access, vba, excel, excel-2007

I have this Excel

[image]

now i want to make some reports using a VBA Macro

**Report 1 (select all tasks)**

Select the number of total tasks no matter if they are completed or not
IMPORTANT! Keep in mind that here are 5 tasks, in another excel may be 20 30 , but all have the same format C6 - task_id, D6 - task_name, E6 task_name ... and so on

**Report 2 (select all WHERE completed is 100%)**

Select the number of total tasks where **completed** column is 100%
IMPORTANT! Keep in mind that here are 5 tasks, in another excel may be 20 30 , but all have the same format C6 - task_id, D6 - task_name, E6 task_name ... and so on

**Report 3 (select all users and retrive information about their productivity)**

Here basicaly i need something like

```
SUM(I6:I10) - SUM(K6:K10) WHERE task_given_to = 'OM'

SUM(I6:I10) - SUM(K6:K10) WHERE task_given_to = 'MN'

SUM(I6:I10) - SUM(K6:K10) WHERE task_given_to = 'NM'
```

IMPORTANT! Keep in mind that here are 5 tasks, in another excel may be 20 30 , but all have the same format C6 - task_id, D6 - task_name, E6 task_name ... and so on

Any help with that?
I must say, in SQL it would be easy ...

Comment: In SQL it *would* be easy, yes. Look into the following: Autofilter, SUMIF function, ADODB to access Excel

Comment: Why the MS Access tag? If you have MS Access, any reason why you cannot just link the sheets as tables and run queries? Re ADODB: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819

Answer (score 0):

Is there any requirement to use VBA ? Unless there is something I am missing, a simple pivot table would be able to do that.

1. Just put the task name as the row field.
2. Apply a filter on completion.
3. User as row field, productivity as data, task type as column.

Isn't it what you are trying to achieve ?

Oh and FYI if this does come from Access you can use MS Query.
Data => Other sources => MS Query => Access database

Then you can just use an SQL query to retrieve data. I'd then make 3 data sheets with 3 different queries and 3 report sheets which would format the data to a more report-like format.

Comment: so what are you saying there, just use Access? i don't really understand because i don't use Excel to often, and for some reasons i need to do this in Excel, but if i really need i will use Access

Comment: No I just thought maybe that data came from Access, but as I said I think one or many pivot table(s) will do just fine for your needs.

Comment: If maybe you can link me an Excel file I could try and show what I mean with a screenshot.

Comment: I managed to do the first two with raw data only, the third I think would need a formula in a new column to make it work because there is no way to do arithmetics in pivot tables to my knowledge. I will think again about this.